# Electron show devtools on new window when using setWindowOpenHandler

Tags: electron, window

With the new electron, event 'new-window' is deprecated and replaced with `BrowserContent.setWindowOpenHandler`.

How to setup various events, including `dom-ready` for opening devtools?

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = createMainWindow();

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
    // Set event listener on to-be-created WebContent
    // { ..., overrideBrowserWindowOptions: { events, enableDevTools: true, etc } }
    return { action: 'allow' };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to additionally intercept the [`did-create-window`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-create-window) event which fires when the window is created:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on("did-create-window", (window, details) => {
    window.webContents.once("dom-ready", () => window.webContents.openDevTools());
});
```

Comment: That's epic, if I want to create identical window that would be recursive process: `winA.webContents.on('', () => { winB.webContents.on(''...`